# How to import and export in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two files: total.vue and completeness.vue. I would visualize the chart from  total.vue into completeness.vue which will be my admin dashboard where I'll put 2 or 3 others charts.

From total.vue I'm going to export my stuff

```
<script>

    import Chart from 'chart.js';
    import JQuery from 'jquery'
    let $ = JQuery
    export default {
        name: 'total_chart',
        mounted() {
            var chart_total = this.$refs.chart_total;
            const ctx = chart_total.getContext("2d");
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
    ...
    ...
    ...
</script>
```

In completeness.vue I'm going then to import like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="total_chart">
        <div id="content">
            <canvas ref="chart_total"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import  chart_total  from '@/components/total'

export default {
  components: {
    chart_total
  }
} 

</script>
```

NO result pointing to the route which I have assigned to completeness.vue.

Suggestions?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you edit your post to add your folder structure? That way we can help with the component import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not actually rendering the component. This is how you should do it:

```html
<template>
    <total-chart>
    </total-chart>
</template>

<script>

import TotalChart from '@/components/total'

export default {
  components: {
    TotalChart
  }
} 

</script>
```

And then your `total-chart` component:

```html
<template>
        <div id="content">
            <canvas ref="chart_total"></canvas>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

    import Chart from 'chart.js';
    import JQuery from 'jquery'
    let $ = JQuery
    export default {
        name: 'total-chart',
        mounted() {
            var chart_total = this.$refs.chart_total;
            const ctx = chart_total.getContext("2d");
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
    ...
    ...
    ...
</script>
```

And just an fyi - you might want to read up on naming components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html